# how can I replace the calendar of vtigercrm with another customized calendar (solar calendar)?

Tags: php, javascript, crm, vtiger

I am modifying the Vtiger CRM environment and have changed its language from English to Persian. Now I want to replace the Vtiger's calendar (which its system is Gregorian) with another calender. You can see the images of these two calenders below:

Gregorian calendar which already being used in Vtiger:
[image: Gregorian calendar]

My solar calendar which I want to use in Persian Vtiger:

[image: Solar calendar]

I believe that I should use my calendar component in `/var/www/html/vtigercrm/jscalendar` but I do not know how to replace the Gregorian calendar with new one. I highly appreciate if you help me.

Comment: please , share more detail

Comment: Pardon, stack is not a place to claim the others to do your job! You go ahead and in case of hitting the wall, ask the others! Another matter to say is that changing js calendar is an easier job compared to it's built-in calendar module. I've done this before and I don't think it can be answered without Verbalization!

Comment: @HPM good point. I [tried](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22968891/383793), but this question is way to broad to answer... If you see such questions, don't hesitate to flag them as too broad and downvoting it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Adapting the datepicker widget

You can write an [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) around your Persian widget, that implements the same interface (objectmethods, *not* UI) as the [original Calendar](http://sourceforge.net/p/vtigercrm/code/HEAD/tree/vtigercrm/trunk/jscalendar/calendar.js) object.  Then vtigercrm can interact with the Adapter as if it was the original, and the Adapter will translate all calls to whatever the Persian widget expects and translate all responses. That `calendar.js` also [patches the Date prototype](http://sourceforge.net/p/vtigercrm/code/HEAD/tree/vtigercrm/trunk/jscalendar/calendar.js#l1582). From a quick glance, it looks like no clear [MVC pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller); the widget acts like both the View and the Controller and the `<input>`-element acts like the Model. But since the user sees it, it is a View too. Which brings us to

#### the internal representation

Since the date `<input>`-element is both the Model and a View either the Persian representation of the date gets POSTed and you need to handle the translation on the server *or* you change it onload *from* Gregorian and onsubmit *to* Gregorian.

If you do the latter, internally vtiger will know only Gregorian and you will have to do the change in all places where dates get displayed.

You could try and adapt what looks like the server model [`vt_DateTime`](http://sourceforge.net/p/vtigercrm/code/HEAD/tree/vtigercrm/trunk/modules/Calendar/Date.php). And if vtiger would use it everywhere, you would be done.... But I went down the rabbit-hole some more and it looks  like the vtiger isn't designed that way... You could clean-up the design and submit a patch, you could find all functions and methods that start with 'format' or you could just post a feature request in the [bugtracker](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/How_to_Access_Bug_Tracker).

Anyway, after inspecting the code I know for sure that this is way beyond a StackOverflow answer.